# Use tsconfig flags for test files but exclude them from build

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have a `tsconfig.json` file containing an explicit `include` pattern for `src/**/*`. I also have tests present in `test/`, but these are only executed using `ts-jest` and I never want to compile them to my `dist` folder or include them when bundling the source code.

This works fine, except I started getting warnings in some test files because of required flags such as `esModuleInterop`. Since `test/` is not included in `tsconfig.json`, not only are the test files ignored when building, but the flags are also not active for the test files.

How can I write a `tsconfig.json` file that

1. Compiles only files in `src/` to `dist/`
2. Still respects flags for files in `test/` and `tools/`

I managed to put a separate `tsconfig.json` file in my `test/` folder and yet another one in my `tools/` folder but I'm wondering if it's possible to avoid this and only have a single file?

Answer (score 4):

To my knowledge, you can't build some files and only type-check others from a single tsconfig. However, to save duplication of the tsconfig flags, you can use the ["extends"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#extends) option:

`project/tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true
    // other options here
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

`project/test/tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json"
  // compilerOptions will be inherited
  // you may need to set "include" here relative to the "test" directory
}
```

Comment: Thanks. While this still means one tsconfig file per directory containing TS files it does simplify things and reduces duplication.

Comment: Another solution I thought about is to turn this around a bit - to have a `tsconfig.json` in the project root which sets all the flags and includes everything, but is never used to build anything. Then you have a separate `tsconfig.json` in the src directory which extends the base one to get the flags. Then you have to make sure to invoke `tsc` from the src folder, or use `tsc --config src/tsconfig.json`. This relies on it being possible to specify a relative `outDir` though, such as `../dist`, I haven't tried it yet. :)